# Deploying SSL certificate to Azure service fabric cluster

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

Found this post on how to deploy SSL certificates to a Azure Service Fabric cluster.

[How to configure SSL on a self hosted Web API in Azure Service Fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35307118/how-to-configure-ssl-on-a-self-hosted-web-api-in-azure-service-fabric)

Where do I find documentation on how to connect to the service fabric node VM's?
Where do I find the name of the "KeyVault"? ...and in general some more info on deploying the service fabric cluster.

Answer (score 1):

For general information about setting up a Service Fabric cluster in Azure, take a look at the following documentation: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-creation-via-arm/

For the KeyVault, it is required when creating a "Secured Cluster" (secured cluster means that you need to have a certificate to be able to control the actual Service Fabric, i.e. create application/services). So if you have a secured cluster in Azure, you'll already have a KeyVault you can use. To list all your KeyVaults, you can the powershell command:

```
Get-AzureRmKeyVault
```

Regarding connecting to the VM nodes. In the Azure Portal, if you open your Service Fabric cluster, you should be able to find the IP and Port ranges needed to RDP into the VMs. All VMs will be on the same IP, with different ports to separate between them.

Note that the answer in the link you refered above was created before Virtual Machine Scale Set (VMSS) was supported by Service Fabric in Azure. On the 23rd of February, the Service Fabric released a new preview that uses VMSS (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azureservicefabric/archive/2016/02/23/service-fabric-sdk-v1-5-175-and-the-adoption-of-virtual-machine-scale-sets.aspx), so the instructions above, while still working, needs to be updated to factor in the scaling part of VMSS.