# Require Service fabric Application on SSl

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

Actually, we want the application which running on fabric want to run on SSL , not fabric.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure SSL on a self hosted Web API in Azure Service Fabric](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35307118/how-to-configure-ssl-on-a-self-hosted-web-api-in-azure-service-fabric)

Comment: Could you explain what you want to do? Do you have a Servic Fabric application with Services that are communicating with each other using Fabric Transport (aka Service Remoting) and you want to change that to HTTPS based communication? Or  do you mean to secure the Fabric Transport communication between the swrvices?